# Implementing generic structs conforming to Hashable protocol. Error : Refernce to generic type 'strA' requires arguments in <...> error

Tags: swift, generics, struct, swift2

I am trying to implement a generic struct which conforms to protocol Hashable.

```
struct strA<T: Equatable>:Hashable, CustomStringConvertible {
private(set) var key: String
private(set) var value: T
private(set) var timeStamp: NSDate

init(leafKey key:String, leafValue value:T){
    self.key = key
    self.value = value
    self.timeStamp = NSDate()
}

var description: String {
    return "\(self.key): \(self.value)"
}

var hashValue: Int {
    return self.key.hashValue
}
}

func == (lhs: strA, rhs: strA) -> Bool {
    return lhs.key == rhs.key
}
```

I get a compile error at the implementation of the equality method.
[image]

I have to make the struct conform to protocol Hashable because it goes inside an array, and its generic because the value can be of any of the Equatable types. ( Am not using 'Any' here because that will take almost everything. )

How do I carry forward with this situation or is there any alternative way to solve this ?

p.s. This is not a duplicate question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Because `strA` is a generic, then the equality method must also be a generic.

```
func ==<T>(lhs: strA<T>, rhs: strA<T>) -> Bool {
    return lhs.key == rhs.key
}
```

--

Side note: All types should begin with a capital letter. So, `StrA` not `strA`.

Comment: Yea. Just for the question I retyped the struct with a random name. And yes. This works.